# Knockout js Table Edit column get onkeyup/ Onchange Latest Value. [Fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/chiks/975ncawv/521/)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a Knockout Model for Table. In Table 1 column is always editable. I wish to get the changed value of this column, i.e when the onchange/onKeyup event occurs the newly changed value should be availanle with me i.e in alert I should receive the newest changed value.

Below is just an sample code snippet. Please find [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chiks/975ncawv/521/)

```
<td>
      <input data-bind="event: {change:$parent.value_changed},value: Menge "/>  
  </td>  


 self.value_changed = ko.observable(self.items());
    refVM.value_changed.subscribe(function (newValue) {
   alert(newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's way more complicated than it needs to be.

1. Observables by default fire change events whenever their value updates. You do not need to create an event binding in HTML to listen to changes. Keep it like this:

   ```
   <input data-bind="value: Menge "/>
   ```
2. To listen the change events fired by this `Menge` observable, simply subscribe to it right after it is created (inside the RowModel constructor).

   ```
   var RowModel = function(bild,artikelnummer, bezeichnung,kategorie,preis,menge,preisgesamt,removePeople, werbemittelId) {
     this.Bild = ko.observable(bild);
     this.Artikelnummer = ko.observable(artikelnummer);
     ...
     this.Menge = ko.observable(menge);
     ...

     this.Menge.subscribe(function(newValue){
       alert(newValue);
     });
   };
   ```

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/975ncawv/538/).

Comment: Thanks Ray, it is always helpful your comments and answers.

Comment: Welcome! I'm always waiting to answer your questions ;) I have ended up knowing your project quite well now.

Comment: Hey Ray, a quick updated question. On a Record Level (Row Level) I have save button, when I click on save button there I need to check if the value of field is changed or not, If changed allow for update(further process).
Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chiks/975ncawv/674/)

Comment: Hi :) I'm seeing two issues, 1. You need curly braces around the first `if`statement in `clickForSave` method. 2. You call `self.loadData(data)` at the end. I'm not sure why you're doing this, but it's causing the initial data to load again. I commented it. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/975ncawv/680/

Comment: self.loadData(data) was just an replica in Fiddle (for my original Project) to Load data from System (updated data).
What Issue I am facing is for Ex. I changed the value in Row 1 but I save the Row2 (Not changed/updated). Now in my Global Variable it has oldMenge Value of Row1 which is  not correct. What I wish to achieve is onSave event, For that particular Record check old value and the newly entered/updated Value, If yes changed for that record go ahead.

Comment: By the way I have an Idea of using in my Model one more datapoint called "OldMenge" which will have original value of that particular Record and then on Save just compare it with newly changed/updated value on Record Level.
Does that sound a feasible solution for you?

Comment: Yes that is a good solution 'Idea of using in my Model one more datapoint called "OldMenge"'... Otherwise if you use global variable you will be saving the data of any row which you updated last. You lose information of the row before that one.